# How can I move a file to a dynamically determined name with bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a testprogram that writes some results into a file "result". I wanna
run the program three times and then store the results in an appropriate file with the
name result1, result2, etc.

I thought something along those lines will do the trick:

```
for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 3;  i++  ))
do
  ./testprogram
  cp result result+'i'    (?????)
  rm result
done
```

I am just not sure how I generate here the filename "result" + "i".

Answer (score 10):

```
for i in {1..3}
do
  ./testprogram
  mv results "result${i}"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
cp result result$i
```